# Integration Limits while finding volumes

Tags: multivariable-calculus

When taking triple integrals , we need to decide the limits of integration of each axis ( x,y and z) . My question is how do i decide which integration limits to take first ?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it doesn't matter which you take first, as long as your integration limits describe the solid you are attempting to find the volume of.

As a very simple example, for the cuboid $[0,1]\times [1,2]\times [0,5]$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ space, it doesn't matter if I take

$$\int_0^1 \int_1^2 \int_0^5 dxdydz$$

or

$$\int_1^2 \int_0^5 \int_0^1 dxdydz.$$

Comment: In this example , you have taken limits to be constant . What would happen if one of the variable like z is dependent on either x or y ?  In that case how do we decide

Comment: You just need to alter your bounding equations to express, say, $x$ in terms of $y$ and $z$. In two dimensions, say you want to integrate $f$ over the region bounded below the curve $y = x^2$ and above the $x$ axis on $[0,1]$. That is, in the area $0\leq y \leq x^2$ and $0\leq x \leq 1$. For each $y$ the corresponding value of $x$ is $\sqrt{y}$. So your area of integration can be described as $\sqrt{y} \leq x \leq 1$ and $0\leq y \leq 1$. Thus $\int_0^1 \int_0^{x^2} f dydx = \int_0^1\int_{\sqrt{y}}^1 f dx dy$. Similar for 3D case.